# Creating a CSS Transition

Tags: javascript, css, button, transition

I'm using the javascript below to display a hidden div on a button click:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mydiv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "none";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
```

How do I make the div fade or "fly" in when I click the button? I thought I could use a webkit transition, but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @gforce301 Please be constructive rather than rude when you comment about problems with a question.

Comment: @user2252688 Please include a [mcve] of your problem or we will be unable to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.style.setProperty()` method to add `webkit transitions` or any other `CSS` from `javascript`, like this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

// example fade effect compatible with most browsers
myDiv.style.setProperty("transition", "opacity .2s ease-in-out");
myDiv.style.setProperty("-moz-transition", "opacity .2s ease-in-out");
myDiv.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "opacity .2s ease-in-out");
```

more on `.style.setProperty()`: [https://developer.mozilla.org/setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).

**Edit:** @RokoC.Buljan pointed out a possible better solution, simply use the `.style['-vendor-prop'] = 'val'` syntax like this:

```
myDiv.style['-moz-transition'] = 'opacity .25s ease-in-out';
```

Comment: ...you can `.style['-vendor-prop'] = "val"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the comment, I didn't know that. Pozdrav

Answer (score 0):

The display property is not an animatable css property.

You need to use a property from the following list to animate anything in css:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties